# Android getting the EditText value from an AlertDialog in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-alertdialog

I am getting a null pointer exception when I click the OK button. and I am trying to get the value form an EditText in an AlertDialog.  I am calling the AlertDialog from a fragment.

I believe this line is the problem
View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.passchange_dialog, null);
I think it is because I am passing null but I am not sure what eles to pass.  Please note I am calling the AlertDialog from a fragment not an Activity.

```
public class fragment_account extends myFragment {

private final String firebase = "https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com";
private String email = "";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
    TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmailAddress);
    email = sp.getString("email", "");
    address.setText(email);

    ImageView imageChangePass = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageChangePass);
    imageChangePass.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showInputDialog(v);
                }
            }
    );
    return view;
}

protected void showInputDialog(final View view) {

    try
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.passchange_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);


        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        EditText edittextOldPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittextOldPass);
                        EditText edittextNewPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittextNewPass);
                        EditText edittextConfirmPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittextConfirmPass);
                        final String oldPass = edittextOldPass.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String newPass = edittextNewPass.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String confirmPass = edittextConfirmPass.getText().toString().trim();

                        Firebase ref = new Firebase(firebase);
                        ref.changePassword(email, oldPass, newPass, new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("myStuff", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should call findViewById on promptView instead of on view variable

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should initialize all those textview's before setting the layout of your dialog instead of inside your onClick method. As you have to access their values, you'll have to declare them final in order to get what the user typed in inside of your onClick function.